# get sale products and stock from woocommerce database

Tags: mysql, sql, woocommerce

from woocommerce site try to make a query which give me a result of product list with stock and sale quantity. But no luck..
the code is here

```
    select *, SUM(`wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta`.`meta_value`) as total from wp_aproduts 
    LEFT JOIN       
        (select *, SUM(`wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta`.`meta_value`) as total 
            from wp_woocommerce_order_items 

            JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta 
                ON wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id = wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id 

                WHERE wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key = '_qty' GROUP BY wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_name
        ) as Z

        ON `wp_aproduts`.`product_name` = wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_name GROUP BY `wp_aproduts`.`product_name`
```

can anyone pls help...

sry for my poor english.

Comment: I don't understand... What is the question here?

Comment: there are some error of this query. but cant find. need to ok this.

Comment: You can use meta query instead

Comment: can u pls help..

Answer (score -1):

woocommerce product stock with sale record..

```
select * from wp_aproduts 
    LEFT JOIN       
        (select wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id, SUM(wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value) AS SALE, `wp_woocommerce_order_items`.`order_item_name` as item, order_item_name
    from wp_woocommerce_order_items 

    JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta 
        ON wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id = wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id 

        WHERE wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key = '_qty' GROUP BY wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_name
        ) as Z

        ON `wp_aproduts`.`product_name` = Z.order_item_name GROUP BY `wp_aproduts`.`product_name`
ORDER BY `wp_aproduts`.`sl_no` ASC
```